# MongoDB - installation error - mongodb setup wizard ended prematurely

Tags: mongodb

I earlier had this issue while installing. Checked with other threads too, but could not able to find a proper solution in my case.

[image: Error screenshot]

**UPDATE :**

CLOSED!

Comment: go to your installed folder e-g `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin` open `cmd` and hit `mongod`. let me know what do you see printed on console

Answer (score 77):

Uncheck the `Install MongoDB Compass` option in the setup wizard. Worked for me.

Comment: It worked for me too in Windows Server 2016 Datacenter edition.

Comment: Windows 10 here,can confirm it only works without Compass.

Comment: This should be fixed in 3.6.6
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-34451

Answer (score 18):

unchecking **Install MongoDB Compass** solves the issue directly from startup wizard while installing in windows10

Comment: Doesn't help with v4.0

Answer (score 8):

For Windows 10, you will have to install MongoDB Compass separately. 
After install MongoDB, then download MongoDB Compass separately from [here](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?jmp=docs&_ga=2.112495044.136631810.1527075999-1083397290.1527075999#compass).
For MongoDB Compass, make sure to select the correct Version (note: the Community Edition version is not the default version) and Platform to download. It should install successfully.

Answer (score 2):

I face exactly the same error, my solution:

My windows user didn't have a password, I set a password for it and used my **username** and **password** to "**Run as a local or domain user**", and my problem fixed.

[image]

**Tip***: I also installed Compass (not separately) and it was not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just ensure you are connected to internet for  MongoDB Compass to be installed too,its mongoDb user graphical interface unchecking it blocks you from enjoying graphical interface.

Answer (score 0):

For those trying to install version 4.0.x
Compass *is* the problem, but you don't get to untick straight away.
According to https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-34451 it's a firewall problem. Disable the firewall or allow access fixed it for me.

Comment: Better would be only to allow only the required ports, nevertheless the hint might be useful in general.

Answer (score 0):

Unchecking the `Install MongoDB Compass` works for me.

Comment: It didn't for me (4.2 - 4.4)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Microsoft Account then solution is to login with local account instead, that is available in account settings.

Once you are logged in with local account, you can complete the installation with local username and password.