# MongoDB - mongodb setup wizard ended prematurely

Tags: mongodb, image, google-chrome, error-handling, installation

I'm not able to install MongoDB(4.2.6). I've downloaded the "MSI" version but even though I'm getting this error message displayed. I have tried unchecking the MongoDB compass option, rebooting the system and installing it again, but then too it is not being installed using all the possible means.

Error message that is being displayed is

> MongoDB Setup Wizard ended prematurely because of an error. Your system has not been modified.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB - installation error - mongodb setup wizard ended prematurely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49721421/mongodb-installation-error-mongodb-setup-wizard-ended-prematurely)

Comment: You also had an image that wasn't displayed in the question. That sounds like the reason for the error...

Answer (score 0):

`first open command prompt using administrator`
[image]

```
after open you go to folder where setup is store using cmd(
and enter your setup name(use cd command for go one folder to another)
```

Comment: I tried doing this, still it is not working. Can you help me out with some other way of solving this?

Comment: Cmd run as administration and try it to install mongodb using cmd

Comment: How do I do that? Can you please tell me the process step wise?

Answer (score 0):

The file concrt140.dll is part of the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable.  Installing that first should allow you to complete this installation..

Comment: I have already installed Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable on the PC. Still it is giving me the same error. Do you have a better solution to this?

Comment: Have you tried running the installer as administrator?

Comment: How do I do that? Can you please tell me the process step wise?